# Advantages to using __fastfail over native functions(kill, ExitProcess, etc.)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was working on a program that in some cases requires to terminate/exit itself instantly.

I was wondering if there was any advantage to using MSVC's "__fastfail" over the native platform functions for termination, like Windows' "ExitProcess" or Linux's "kill".

Comment: [documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/fastfail?view=vs-2017) "Use __fastfail to terminate the process using minimal overhead." (preceeded by details on how it differs from "normal" termination)

Comment: Meant to quickly terminate a corrupted process, the kind where you can't rely on user-mode code to still execute correctly.  Like ExitProcess().  It goes straight to ring0 kernel code.